# Rasa + M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa, macos-big-sur

I installed Rasa on the new Macbook Pro M1 with Big Sur 11.0.1, and get the following problem when using any Rasa command (init, train, …):

`zsh: illegal hardware instruction rasa init`

I attached the associated console crash report. The problem seems to be related to `libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib`

Anybody ran into this issue or know what the issue is?
Thank you.

```
Process:               Python [1217]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.8.6 (3.8.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        zsh [1178]
Responsible:           Electron [1135]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-12-11 18:14:24.221 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        ABF4F2BE-70FE-0B3B-B70B-FA320F32EB73


Time Awake Since Boot: 420 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1217]

Application Specific Information:
/Users/mikey/Documents/Prototype/rasa-workshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x0000000150ac5264 tensorflow::monitoring::MetricDef<(tensorflow::monitoring::MetricKind)1, long long, 2>::MetricDef<char [11], char [7]>(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view, absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view, char const (&) [11], char const (&) [7]) + 68
1   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x0000000150abe01b tensorflow::monitoring::Counter<2>* tensorflow::monitoring::Counter<2>::New<char const (&) [46], char const (&) [58], char const (&) [11], char const (&) [7]>(char const (&) [46], char const (&) [58], char const (&) [11], char const (&) [7]) + 91
2   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x0000000150ac95c1 _GLOBAL__sub_I_loader.cc + 49
3   dyld                            0x0000000200a33079 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 559
4   dyld                            0x0000000200a33478 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
5   dyld                            0x0000000200a2dd1a ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 492
6   dyld                            0x0000000200a2dc85 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 343
7   dyld                            0x0000000200a2bb82 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 188
8   dyld                            0x0000000200a2bc22 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 82
9   dyld                            0x0000000200a1c6a2 dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 82
10  dyld                            0x0000000200a27569 dlopen_internal + 609
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2032efd0 dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 177
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2031d87e dlopen + 28
13  org.python.python               0x0000000108b5eda7 _PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr + 288
14  org.python.python               0x0000000108b38b1b _PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec + 540
15  org.python.python               0x0000000108b384f7 _imp_create_dynamic + 291
16  org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
17  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
18  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
19  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
20  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
21  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
22  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
23  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
24  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
25  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
26  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
27  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
28  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
29  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
30  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
31  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
32  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
33  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
34  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
35  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
36  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
37  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
38  org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
39  org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
40  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
41  org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
42  org.python.python               0x0000000108b10aa8 builtin_exec + 581
43  org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
44  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
45  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
46  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
47  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
48  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
49  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
50  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
51  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
52  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
53  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
54  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
55  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
56  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
57  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
58  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
59  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
60  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
61  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
62  org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
63  org.python.python               0x0000000108b0fc75 builtin___import__ + 122
64  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d47e cfunction_call_varargs + 171
65  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
66  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
67  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
68  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
69  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
70  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
71  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
72  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
73  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
74  org.python.python               0x0000000108b377a7 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1921
75  org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
76  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
77  org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
78  org.python.python               0x0000000108b10aa8 builtin_exec + 581
79  org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
80  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
81  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
82  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
83  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
84  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
85  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
86  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
87  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
88  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
89  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
90  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
91  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
92  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
93  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
94  org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
95  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
96  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
97  org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
98  org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
99  org.python.python               0x0000000108b0fc75 builtin___import__ + 122
100 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d47e cfunction_call_varargs + 171
101 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
102 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
103 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
104 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
105 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
106 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
107 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
108 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
109 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
110 org.python.python               0x0000000108b377a7 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1921
111 org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
112 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
113 org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
114 org.python.python               0x0000000108b10aa8 builtin_exec + 581
115 org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
116 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
117 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
118 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
119 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
120 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
121 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
122 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
123 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
124 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
125 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
126 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
127 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
128 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
129 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
130 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
131 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
132 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
133 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
134 org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
135 org.python.python               0x0000000108b0fc75 builtin___import__ + 122
136 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d47e cfunction_call_varargs + 171
137 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
138 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
139 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
140 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
141 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
142 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
143 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
144 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
145 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
146 org.python.python               0x0000000108b377a7 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1921
147 org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
148 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
149 org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
150 org.python.python               0x0000000108b10aa8 builtin_exec + 581
151 org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
152 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
153 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
154 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
155 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
156 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
157 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
158 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
159 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
160 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
161 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
162 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
163 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
164 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
165 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
166 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
167 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
168 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
169 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
170 org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
171 org.python.python               0x0000000108b0fc75 builtin___import__ + 122
172 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d47e cfunction_call_varargs + 171
173 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
174 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
175 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
176 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
177 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
178 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
179 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
180 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
181 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
182 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
183 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
184 org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
185 org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
186 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
187 org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
188 org.python.python               0x0000000108b10aa8 builtin_exec + 581
189 org.python.python               0x0000000108aab899 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 169
190 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d1f9 PyVectorcall_Call + 108
191 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1accc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 31274
192 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
193 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
194 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
195 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a747 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29861
196 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
197 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
198 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a72b _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29833
199 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
200 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
201 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
202 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
203 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
204 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
205 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
206 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ec4a object_vacall + 352
207 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7ed8d _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 219
208 org.python.python               0x0000000108b3764f PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1577
209 org.python.python               0x0000000108b18bbe _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22812
210 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
211 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
212 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
213 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
214 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d917 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 227
215 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
216 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
217 org.python.python               0x0000000108a7d7b2 function_code_fastcall + 106
218 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1db6d call_function + 346
219 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1a804 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30050
220 org.python.python               0x0000000108b1e687 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1947
221 org.python.python               0x0000000108b131ff PyEval_EvalCode + 51
222 org.python.python               0x0000000108b4c48d run_eval_code_obj + 102
223 org.python.python               0x0000000108b4b8dc run_mod + 82
224 org.python.python               0x0000000108b4a7a8 PyRun_FileExFlags + 160
225 org.python.python               0x0000000108b49e95 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 271
226 org.python.python               0x0000000108b61828 Py_RunMain + 1870
227 org.python.python               0x0000000108b61b6f pymain_main + 306
228 org.python.python               0x0000000108b61bbd Py_BytesMain + 42
229 libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2032d631 start + 1

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc65cb8 0x7ffdffc63000 + 11448
1   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc6fee0 0x7ffdffc63000 + 52960
2   runtime                         0x00007ffdffc70c3c 0x7ffdffc63000 + 56380

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0xe2a123700caa0023  rbx: 0x0000000151b82d50  rcx: 0x0000000151b82d7e  rdx: 0x000000000000002d
  rdi: 0x00000003022c7750  rsi: 0x0000000151b82d50  rbp: 0x00000003022c7730  rsp: 0x00000003022c7680
   r8: 0x0000000000000039   r9: 0x0000000151b82db8  r10: 0x00000000ffe01fff  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x00000003022c7750  r13: 0x0000000151b82db8  r14: 0x00007fbe894d9340  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x0000000150ac5264  rfl: 0x0000000000000202


Translated Code Information:
  tmp0: 0x0000000150ac5264 tmp1: 0x4529f8c5c057f8c5 tmp2: 0x000000b045c748a0


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 31841
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.2G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.2G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=874.8M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=874.8M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            76.1M       26 
MALLOC guard page                   96K        4 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         360.0M        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Rosetta Arena                     2048K        1 
Rosetta Generic                    668K      164 
Rosetta IndirectBranch             192K        2 
Rosetta JIT                      128.0M        1 
Rosetta Return Stack               160K       16 
Rosetta Thread Context             160K       16 
Stack                             16.0M        1 
Stack Guard                         16K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                       62.0M      307 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)           225.4M       18         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            21.1M      374 
__DATA_CONST                      11.6M      185 
__DATA_DIRTY                       501K       85 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       726.4M      153 
__OBJC_RO                         61.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2466K        2 
__TEXT                           468.0M      354 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                        4.3G      572 
shared memory                       32K        2 
unshared pmap                     2432K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              6.4G     2293 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     5.9G     2293 


System Profile:
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Boot Volume File System Type: apfs
Memory Module: lp_ddr4
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 0.0
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 0.0
Model: MacBookPro17,1, BootROM 6723.50.2, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme, wl0: Sep 11 2020 18:25:33 version 18.20.222.10.7.8.97 FWID 01-17360706
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.1f5, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this and sadly Rasa doesn't work yet on M1 Macs.

As shown in the initial error, the issue is the lack of AVX instructions on ARM based processors. As far as I know, AVX has been a prerequisite for most machine learning packages. In this case it's needed for Tensorflow.

Apple does have a [fork of Tensorflow](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) to enable it to run on their new chips, but it's based on the release candidate version of Tensorflow (2.4).

I tried using this fork with the latest Rasa version which allows it to finish installing but training doesn't work. I'm not sure on the specifics of why.. I believe once Tensorflow 2.4 is out of RC, one of the next versions of Rasa will pick it up and work out the bugs.

In the meantime I'm using an Ubuntu VM on Google cloud until things can catch up.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Chris. I will look at Ubunto VM on Google cloud in the meantime as well.

Comment: Did you consider using docket containers instead?